# Problem with I2C

Tags: i2c, atmega2560

I trying to make a project to write and i2c display from a renault megane vehicle. There is many people showing it but there is no code that i can use.

So i buy a cheap analyzer and i can clearly see what radio says to display.

Now i try to do it with arduino... but there is something wrong... i can just read a sequence of "01000110" thats i think that is begin transmission ... but what i write with "Wire.write" is not sending or something... Im so frustrating ... if anyone can tell me why im not receiving more data than 01000110 will be awesome. I will give 2 screens to let us know more.

This is the sniff from the radio

[image: Display i2c data]

This is the sniff from my code

[image: Arduino i2c data]

As you can see only the 01000110 bits is same for both, but there is no more data...

This is my arduino code

```
    #include <Wire.h>
int _mrq = 2;
void setup() {
  pinMode(_mrq, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(_mrq, HIGH);

  Wire.begin();
  Wire.setClock(7140);
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x23);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(_mrq, LOW);
  sendInit(0x01, 0x01);
  digitalWrite(_mrq, HIGH);
  delay(100);
  digitalWrite(_mrq, LOW);
  sendInit(0x01, 0x10);
  digitalWrite(_mrq, HIGH);
  Wire.endTransmission();
}

void loop() {
  delay(500);
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x23);
  digitalWrite(_mrq, LOW);
  sendInit(0x01, 0x01);
  Wire.write(0x0c);
  Wire.write(0x90);
  Wire.write(0x7e);
  Wire.write(0x72);
  Wire.write(0x01);
  Wire.write(0x20);
  Wire.write(0x4c);
  Wire.write(0x4f);
  Wire.write(0x53);
  Wire.write(0x34);
  Wire.write(0x30);
  Wire.write(0x20);
  Wire.write(0x20);
  sendInit(0x01, 0x11);
  digitalWrite(_mrq, HIGH);
  Wire.endTransmission();
  delay(1);
}

void sendInit(int a, int b)
{
  delay(20);
  Wire.write(a);
  delay(100);
  Wire.write(b);
  delay(20);
}
```

Comment: so, what is your question?

Comment: The NAK that you're getting is stopping any further communication. Either whatever you're sending to doesn't like what you're sending, or it's wired up wrong.

Comment: Please tell us, how everything is wired up. Also: What voltage levels do the Atmega2560 and the I2C display use?

Comment: @chrisl I have 3 cables, PIN 2 is MRQ that is a stuff that use radio / display, and pin 20 and 21 (SDA/SCL) display uses 12v but sda/scl is digital and works from 0 to 5.

Comment: What is MRQ here? Has it something to do with the display? The delays around `Wire.write()` are meaningless. This function only puts the data into a buffer. The actual transmission is done only in `Wire.endTransmission()`

Comment: @chrisl nope https://i.gyazo.com/b568257e5489418adaafaaa700c23234.png now i put MRQ to ground before endtransmission and then high again... but sill missing all, only 01000110 is received (again)

Comment: Please try to add a delay between outputting ground to MRQ and `Wire.endTransmission()`. I think the MRQ pin activates the I2C peripheral of the display. It might need some time, before it is ready to answer.

Comment: After reading something about I2C i know that i got NACK... so something goes wrong... but in the radio sniff it get ACK so its OK ... maybe the speed is the problem ? https://i.gyazo.com/6c397a8063fce2bb183753653bc100ba.png (radio) https://i.gyazo.com/2b5190053f046b0402271bb6204a8f0c.png (arduino) (i set speed to 7140 (7.14 Khz with Wire.setClock(7140), its ok ?

Comment: Only specific values are valid for the frequency. You cannot set it to arbitrary values. At least thats what the documentation says. Have you included the delay before endTransmission?

Comment: yep, i added a 500 microseconds after and before endTransmission